# Appending arrays together in R

Tags: r, loops, append, rbind

I'm having some trouble taking the iris3 dataset (classic iris dataset split into multidimensional array by Species) into a new 150x5 data frame in R. I have code below that works, but I'm unsure if this is using the most efficient way or if my syntax is 'best practice.' Specifically, I want to skip the step of assigning Species-specific dataframes and simply put them all into the final output in shorter steps. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

```
iris3 <- iris3 # load data
vec <- c('setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica') 
ind <- seq(3)
dat <- data.frame() # initialize 

for (i in vec) {
  for (j in ind) {
    df <- as.data.frame(cbind(iris3[,,j], rep(i, 50))) # creating a column to assign Species name
    assign(x = i, value = df, envir = .GlobalEnv) # is it possible to not assign these and still get same answer? 
  }
    dat <- rbind(dat, get(i)) # when I move this up a line, it doesn't work properly
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you a similar output. It uses both the `purrr` and `dplyr` packages. I'm not sure if it's considered "*best practice*" but it is a lot cleaner and easier to follow.

```
# iterate over the 3rd dimension of the array
# convert whatever is found on the 3rd dimension as a dataframe
# ouput is a named list
a <- apply(iris3, 3, as.data.frame)

# iterate over the named list and run a function 
# first parameter is the data in the list and the second parameter is the name
# adding the nm [name] as a data point in the data frame
# output is a list
b <- purrr::imap(a, function(dta, nm){dta$species <- nm; dta})

#bind the rows together in a single dataframe
c <- dplyr::bind_rows(b)
```